# R Variable Initialization Trouble: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r, loops, variables, statistics, regression

I am trying to regress slices of two financial time series against each other, and store the results of each regression in a single object. When run this code, I get 50+ of the same error

```
50: In lm_store[counter - lookback] <- lm(SP[(counter - lookback):counter] ~  ... :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

Maybe I am initializing lm_store wrong, but I have not been able to find a solution despite repeated variations. At the end I print out `lm_store[5]` just to verify the results of the regressions. Thank you for your help.

```
#Import necessary packages
require(quantmod)
require(ggplot2)

#Write in the ticker symbols of the pair
tickers <- c("GS","JPM")

#Pull data down for symbols
A <- getSymbols(tickers[1],auto.assign=FALSE)
B <- getSymbols(tickers[2],auto.assign=FALSE)

#Strip data such as high and low prices
A <- A[,4]
B <- B[,4]

#Create a time series of the spread & rename header
S <- A-B
colnames(S) <- "Spread.Close"

#Separate the index of times from the spread data for regression
TS <- index(S)
SP <- coredata(S)

#Perform regressions of past 'lookback' days, incrementing by 1, beginning at T = lookback+1
#Store regression data in vector
lookback <- 250
counter <- lookback+1
lm_store = NULL
while (counter<length(SP)) {
    lm_store[counter-lookback] <- lm(SP[(counter-lookback):counter]~TS[(counter-lookback):counter]);
    counter <- counter+1;
  }

print(lm_store[5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite straightforward. You're using the wrong structure to store your results. You need to use a `list`. Note the use of `[[` vs `[`

```
...
lm_store <- list()
while (counter<length(SP)) {
    lm_store[[counter-lookback]] <- lm(SP[(counter-lookback):counter]~TS[(counter-lookback):counter]);
    counter <- counter+1;
  }

print(lm_store[[5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

lm_store is initialized to an empty vector (class NULL).  When you pass the results of lm to lm_store, you are passing back a class of 'lm' which is a list of 12 elements.  What you need to do is as follows:

```
lm_store = list()
while (counter<length(SP)) {
    lm_store[[counter-lookback]] <- lm(SP[(counter-lookback):counter]~TS[(counter  lookback):counter]);
    counter <- counter+1;
  }

print(lm_store[[5]])
```

Note the double brackets '[[]]' for lists in R.  That should fix your problem.